# No click when playSoundEffect is called

Tags: android

I attach a listener to my button in onCreate:

```
Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonEnter);
    enterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
        }
    });
```

The button has

```
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
```

The debugger stops in the onClick() routine, so the call is made, but the click doesn't happen. Keyboard clicks are heard in a nearby editText box, so it is not a matter of system settings.  What else could it be?

Comment: found any solution? I never got this to work... Legend has it you have to enable click sounds on the tablet settings, but I've double checked they're enabled and nothing ....

Comment: Still looking for the answer

Comment: I also need an answer for this so + 1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I came across the same situation, The trick was, to use Audiomanager.

define an AudioManager in the Activity class.

```
AudioManager audioManager;
```

Initialise in onCreate.

```
audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

In the click method, use the audioManager to play the sound.

```
public void play(View view) {
    audioManager.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK,1.0f);
}
```

Note that the volume is given as `1.0f` if you don't specify the volume, you won't hear any sound.